# MySql Data Replication - how do stored procedure, functions and PHP SQL queries work?

Tags: php, mysql

I will setup DR (Master-Slave) for Mysql databases and I'm confused about how Data Replication works with NON-DETERMINISTIC functions and stored procedures.

I have 3 questions (same question for different cases):

1. In PHP, if I do a query `insert into person values (now(), 'bob');`, how does the replication work since `now()` will be different on slave vs master. Is the `now()` call calculated on the master before being pushed to the logs that will be interpreted by the slave or the slave will also calculated `now()` and get a different value?
2. In Mysql functions, if I do a query `"insert into person values (now(), 'bob');` inside the function, how does the replication works since `now()` will be different on slave vs master. Is the `now()` call calculated on the master before being pushed to the logs that will be interpreted by the slave or the slave will also calculated `now()` and get a different value?
3. In a Mysql stored procedure, if I do a query `insert into person values (now(), 'bob');` inside the procedure, how does the replication work since `now()` will be different on slave vs master. Is the `now()` call calculated on the master before being pushed to the logs that will be interpreted by the slave or the slave will also calculate `now()` and get a different value?

Answer (score 0):

now() will always be evaluated by the master, and the resultant data will be replicated. Your data will be the same master and slave.